# Чем удобно проверять RESTFul API?

Tags: rest, тестирование, поиск-программ

Для проверки работы API я использую браузер. Это было удобно до того момента, как я начал реализовывать post, put и delete методы. Мне кажется, что не стоит тратить время на написание тулзы для проверки API. Поисковики ничего разумного не выдают по этому поводу. Есть нормальные программы для тестирования API под win?

Comment: А чем вас cURL не устраивает?

Comment: Продолжайте тестировать в браузере! https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/search/?q=rest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если имеется ввиду ручное тестирование, то для браузеров имеется много плагинов для выполнения HTTP запросов. 
Вот например приложение для Chrome [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая замечательная программка как Postman, вы там можете создать запросы, указать метод. Для теста можно в запросе указать формат данных JSON, Postman вам отобразит.

Comment: Извините, а чем ваш ответ отличается от уже ранее данных?

Comment: Я не увидел предыдущий, а также уточнил про то, что можно в Postman настроить приём данных в формате JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Вообще, для рест нынче моден swagger. Во многих языках можно на лету генерить для него всё на основании аннотаций. К примеру, мы на ноде используем генератор самописный типо [express-swagger-generator](https://github.com/pgroot/express-swagger-generator). Он по аннотациям к методу генерит данные для свагера и запускает его потом.

После чего можно его открыть в браузере и выполнять любые запросы в удобном виде. Выглядит как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Postman так же существует в виде отдельного приложения для Windows, Linux, MacOS.
Скачать можно тут: https://www.getpostman.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

Я использую SoapUI как отдельное приложение. Программа работает и под Win и под Ubuntu. Позволяет тестировать как Rest запросы, так и SOAP запросы. Из удобного в ней - это возможность тестирования сервисов, сохранение запросов. Из недостатков, иногда она оборачивает запросы в ненужные обертки.  Для работы из браузера я использую расширение для chrome Talend API Tester - Free Edition. Быстро и удобно.